# javascript confirm dialog not working after adding some other JS code

Tags: javascript, jquery, layout, modal-dialog

i have this code, what usese the container layout (jquery.layout):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var myLayout = $('#container').layout();
var containerWidth = myLayout.state.container.innerWidth;
myLayout.options.west.onresize= function(){ customSaveState();}
myLayout.options.east.onresize= function(){ customSaveState();}
var msize = customLoadState();
myLayout.sizePane("west", msize[0]);
myLayout.sizePane("east", msize[1]);
function customSaveState () {
  var westCurrentSize      = myLayout.state.west.size;
  var eastCurrentSize      = myLayout.state.east.size;
  saveSizes(westCurrentSize, eastCurrentSize);
};
});
```

It works as expected.
But my modal confirm dialog doesent. The confirm source looks like that:

```
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-confirm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $confirm["title"];?></h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p><?php echo $confirm["caption"];?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-left">
                    <?php echo $confirm["cancel"];?>
          </i>
        </a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo $confirm["link"];?>">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
          <?php echo $confirm["doit"];?>
        </i>
        </a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

The Modal dialog pops up with disabled background (the window behind the modal dialog), but also the modal dialog itself is disabled.

The same modal code in other windows works well. It looks like, that the part

```
var myLayout = $('#container').layout();
```

is relevant. If i remove this, then the modal dialog works, but the container layout doesent.

JN

Comment: any console error?

Comment: there is no console error. Nothing. JN